# Changing visibility of a button

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have the following button on every page:

```
  <a href="#"  class="mainMenu sideBarButton orange" style="visibility:hidden" id="myButton">Start</a>
```

and a popup form which has the following button

```
   <input type="button" value="Log in" onClick="assignValue()";/>
```

clicking this calls:
        function assignValue(){
              sessionStorage.setItem("booleanLoggedIn", true);
      }

And I'm hoping that the value associated with key "`booleanLoggedIn`" is true for the whole session, so that:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var loggedIn = sessionStorage.getItem('booleanLoggedIn');
     if (loggedIn){  
     document.getElementById('myButton').style.visibility="visible";

    }
```

means that as long as the user is logged in, the button "`Start`" will appear on the page?

But this is not working correctly, and I have no idea why. I know that the value "`true`" is getting stored correctly..

Comment: Are your sure `sessionStorage.getItem('booleanLoggedIn')` has correct value ?

Comment: yes I'm quite sure.. what's more.. it shows up once on chrome and then never appears again. On firefox it fails to show up at all..

Comment: You test it in one tab right or you are using many tabs to check this login status?

Comment: One tab.. unless opening another tab in another browser would affect this?

Comment: The `onload` snippet is missing a closing bracket. Is it missing the bracket in your page's code, too?

Comment: @SonicProtein I ask because sessionStorage works only for one tab. If you go to the same page in another tab/window then browser will create new sessionStorage object.

Comment: Also, your "Log in" button has a misplaced semicolon outside `onClick`'s value.